# Compiler Robustness ... Naivete

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I use Visual Studio Professional 2012.  I pre-compiled  a class (header and source) successfully.  Days later, when compiling another class (for the moment header only) that is utilizing the previous one, the compiler caught a missing reference `if(this != &rhs)` and semicolon `rhs.root = nullptr;.`

Perhaps it is my naivete and lack of knowledge about how compilers work but I thought a compiler was robust to catch errors such as these. It appeared to me that only when a specific block of code was required did the compiler feel the need to check it.

I have read about just-in-time compilation and learned how assembly compilers perform a two-pass compilation with symbols first and then syntax.  I have not taken a course in compiler construction at my university and I know such courses give great insight into parsers, etc.

The code section where it failed to catch the error is this move assignment operator:

```
Tree &operator=(Tree &&rhs) 
{ 
    if(this != rhs)    <--------- no reference to the rhs
    { 
        root = std::move(rhs.root); 
        rhs.root = nullptr      <----------- no semicoln
    } 
    return *this; 
}
```

The errors were generated while compiling boost variant, as well as my visitor class member:

```
bool operator() (Tree<std::string>& tree) const {
    return tree.load(tree);
}
```

as well as a host of other errors related to boost serialization.  The fix was to, of course, correct the missing reference and semicolon but I want to understand why this was caught apparently only when the compiler needed to touch this code?

Comment: There are a lot of different questions in this text, you should split them up and ask a single question for each topic.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a more complete code sample, as it's hard to understand what might be wrong with your code, and see why the compiler didn't catch it.

Comment: There's a whole lot of misconceptions here. "Just-In-Time" compilation isn't the same as eliminating / ignoring unreachable code. Also, modern compilers aren't "one-pass" or "two-pass", you need a crapload of passes to enable state-of-the-art features with decent error reporting. (Eric Lippert [outlines this for C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/04/how-many-passes.aspx), and consider that a C++ compiler is much more complex than a C# one if for no other reason than that it has to deal with templates and optimising native code.)

Comment: Also, using precompiled headers doesn't mean that all of the C/C++ code in them *must* be compiled somehow. It's entirely possible that the bits that caused problems for you later on were in a context that didn't afford precompilation, and I assume the precompiler is smart enough to just skip those and let the main compiler take care of doing the error checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a template class?

Because semantic analysis of templates makes only sense when they are instantiated. That is, if it is a template, the compiler should generate an error at the missing semicolon (syntactic error), but not at the == operator.

The following code compiles with g++:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
        void q(A &a) {
                if (this == a) {}
        }

};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        A<int> x;
        //x.q(x);
}
```

But doesn't compile when

```
        x.q(x);
```

is uncommented.

Comment: It is a template class; well the outer class is a template class whereby the inner class shares the outer class template type.